# Indexing data to ElasticSearch without using curl

Tags: curl, indexing, elasticsearch

I'm quite new to ElasticSearch as well as networking (TCP/IP, HTTP/HTTPS). 
I have ElasticSearch running with Kibana3 interface and I'm able to index data just fine (using curl). The next thing I'm working on is to upload data from a micro-controller - Arduino with a WiFi shield to be exact. How exactly do I index data to ElasticSearch? The WiFi module has HTTP and TCP/IP functionality but I'm not sure how would I go about that.

I would appreciate it with any direction and resources that can help me with that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have HTTP available, then all you have to do is PUT to your index with the data you want to index. With your HTTP module:

```
PUT http://logstash_server/your_index/:id
```

Where `:id` is the ID of the record to insert, and the body of the request would be your document to be indexed, as JSON.

That said, if you're ultimately looking to get data into Kibana, then consider using something like [Logstash](http://logstash.net/). It has a wide range of available inputs and can output to multiple targets, including Elasticsearch for consumption through Kibana. It also offers UDP interfaces, which are often preferable for logging.

In your case, you'd just set up a TCP listener with an Elasticsearch output:

```
input {
  tcp {
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    port => 5228
    codec => json_lines
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "localhost"
  }
}
```

Then you'd just open a TCP connection to your logstash server on port 5228, and send a line of JSON which includes an `@timestamp` field with the current time, an `@version` field with a value of 1, then any other fields you want to index. You can keep that socket open and send multiple lines, and each line will result in a new record being indexed; you just make sure each line is newline-terminated.

If you want to use a different input format, then you could look at the [Logstash input codecs](http://www.logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/) to select an input format that you like better.

Comment: Just want to confirm if I were to use HTTP, all I need is to use PUT and not XPUT, correct? E.g. PUT http://local:9200/test/log1 -d '{"Name":"John", "Age":21}'

I want to get data into Kibana for visualization, but is it necessary to use Logstash? If not, can you give me an example of how to send the correct format for JSON?

Comment: Correct, when you see `curl -XPUT`, the "use this method" switch is `-X` and the method is `PUT`. I haven't used Kibana without Logstash, so I'm not sure I can say what the format should exactly be.

Comment: A follow up question, can I use POST method instead of PUT?

Comment: They have different semantics in Elasticsearch; PUT is used to update a known document, POST is used to create a new document. See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-doc.html

Comment: ISO8601, I believe. ie, `2015-03-02T19:53:15.675Z`

Comment: I tried the methods you gave me but it didn't work for both of them. Any more suggestions?

Comment: How are they failing? ES is pretty straightforward - if you give it a well-formed POST it should insert.

Comment: When I started logstash with a configuration file, below is what I got.

>> Using milestone 2 input plugin 'tcp'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}
>> WARN: org.elasticsearch.discovery: [myPC] waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery Exception in thread ">output" org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]

Comment: I'm using ESP8266 wifi module, in case you want to look it up.

Comment: That looks like Logstash was unable to locate your Elasticsearch server. Logstash will spin up a non-storing ES node and attempt to connect to your cluster; if it can't find the master to connect to, it can't emit anything to the indexes. Check the Logstash docs on configuring your ES cluster.

Comment: I use a new configuration file and now it only shows the first message 
>"Using milestone 2 input plugin 'tcp'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}"
Is this typical?